# How to modify iOS App Icon with fastlane action?

Tags: ios, testflight, fastlane, appicon

[image]

I use the Fastlane action to upload the app to TestFlight, and I want to modify the app icon. In Xcode, this "Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name" option in the Build Settings of Targets can modify the app icon, but I can't find the action of Fastlane to modify the app icon, and I used the two actions of badge and app_icon below but it didn't work.

the Fastlane file as below:

```
lane :beta do |values|
badge(custom: './Assets.xcassets/AppIconBeta.appiconset/IconBeta-1024.png')
#badge(path: './Assets.xcassets/AppIconBeta.appiconset/IconBeta-1024.png')
#app_icon('./Assets.xcassets/AppIconBeta.appiconset/IconBeta-1024.png')

match(type: 'appstore',readonly: false,app_identifier:'com.health-beta',force_for_new_devices: false,force: true)
gym(scheme: 'Health - PROD', export_method: 'app-store')
pilot
end
```

Comment: [Maybe](https://github.com/KrauseFx/fastlane-plugin-appicon) or [maybe](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/badge/)

Answer (score -1):

In Fastlane script you can explicitly add a badge and some additional changes to your icon using `badge` https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/badge/

```
badge(custom: <badge path>)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, and I have tried the badge you provided, but it not work, this action is deprecated.